# Import data into SQL server from web url

Tags: sql-server-2008, import-from-excel

I'm looking for some suggestions on how best to do this.

We have a third party application which exposes reports through a URL.  When the URL is hit it creates a simple excel 2007 file containing the data.

I need to bring this into a SQL 2008 database server.  This isn't a one time thing and has to be scheduled to run once a day.

What is the best way to go about hooking the two up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for an SSIS package to do the download and the import and schedule it as a SQL Agent Job.

Answer (score 2):

I'd write a .net program to download the excel document from the URL. Open it and process its contents to a DataTable applying whatever validation it requires at this point then push it into the database using [sqlbulkcopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) and either emailing an admin or writing to the event log if its well monitored on any failures.

Then schedule it up to run daily on your server.